# What argument names do you prefer in constructors? Suffixes, prefixes or smth else?

Tags: c++, constructor, identifier, notation

For example, I sometimes use "Set" suffix, like that:

```
ClassA
{
    public:
        ClassA(int xSet, int ySet):
            x(xSet),
            y(ySet)
        {
            ;
        }

    private:
        int x, y;
};
```

So, is there a better way to write xSet and ySet?

Comment: Why not simply use the same name?  Use `this->x(x)` to initialize the member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer is to name the parameters for what they
are: `initialX` and `initialY` (or in setters, `newX` and
`newY`).  Following this logic, the member variables should
probably be `currentX` and `currentY`—the usual rule is
that variable names should be qualified nouns.

Which is all nice in theory.  In practice, it seems that the
above might be overkill (or a too rigorous application of the
theory).  At least, every where I've worked, there's been
a convention about naming members, so that one can immediately
see whether a name is a member or not.  Ideally, it shouldn't be
necessary, but practically, we don't work in an ideal world.
The two most common conventions I've seen are `m_` or `my` as
prefixes for the member names (with `s_` or `our` for static
members).  The other widespread conventions (using an underscore
as prefix or suffix) should be avoided, because leading and
trailing underscores aren't very visible, and make the code hard
to read.  (Leading underscores also tend to be used for very
special symbols in the implementation, and should be especially
avoided.)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes people chose to use special suffixes/prefixes for data members to differentiate them from other variables/parameters. Popular naming conventions are:

1) m_ prefix (e.g. m_x);

2) _ suffix (e.g. x_);

I personally prefere x_ because it's less typing.

Comment: But aren't the underscore prefixes reserved by the compiler? I sometimes used underscore like x_ which resulted in some logic errors, because of writing x instead of x_ or similar. But thanks for the post! 
Any other ideas?

Comment: A underscore as first char is reserved, not every underscore anywhere.

Comment: But an underscore at the end is also difficult to read, and should be avoided.  Prefixing `m_` or `my` are valid solutions, _if_ you go this route.

Comment: What does m_ stand for?

Comment: @user3496846 I guess "m" stands for "member"

Comment: @AlexT That may be the origins, but it is actually used as just an arbitrary signal: `m_` means member (and `s_` means static member.

Answer (score 2):

Every project/team/organization follows their own coding guidelines. If you are looking for something to adopt for yourself or your team, a google search for "C/C++ coding guidelines" should give you some useful links to get started.

Where I work, we use  underscore (_) as the suffix of class member data. The arguments to constructors are the same names without the underscore.

Comment: Yes, this works well to visually distinguish instance vars from local vars. In languages that permit it, I prefer underscore prefix. Neither should be used on public fields aka properties.

Comment: Alright, I guess underscore is the best as it gets all the support here :) Will check out guidelines, thanks.